# Issue in implementation of Segment Trees

Tags: c++, data-structures, segment-tree

I am trying to implement Segment Trees for extracting min value from a given interval in an array.[Reference - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/ ]

The following is the code for the same.

```
//This code inplements segment trees for extracting min from a given interval of an array

#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
#include "cmath"
#include "climits"
using namespace std;


class segmentTree
{
private:
    int /* $$$ float $$$ */ *tree;
    int n,h;    //h represents height of tree
    std::vector<int /* $$$ float $$$ */> timeForStick;  //vector to store the input array first
public:
    segmentTree(int noOfNodes)
    {
        n=noOfNodes;
        h=(int)(ceil(log2(n)));
        tree = new int /* $$$ float $$$ */ [(int)(2*pow(2,h))-1];
    }


    int getMid(int segmentStart, int segmentEnd)
    {
        return segmentStart+(segmentEnd-segmentStart)/2;
    }

    int /* $$$ float $$$ */ getMin(int/* $$$ float $$$ */ a, int/* $$$ float $$$ */ b)
    {
        return (a>b)? b: a;
    }


    void getInput(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            float /* $$$ float $$$ */ temp;
            cin>>temp;
            timeForStick.push_back(temp);   //the input array is stored in a vector timeForStick
        }
    }

    int /* $$$ float $$$ */ constructST(int segmentStart, int segmentEnd, int currentIndex)
    {
        if (segmentEnd==segmentStart)
        {
            tree[currentIndex]=timeForStick[segmentEnd];
            return timeForStick[segmentEnd];
        }

        int mid=getMid(segmentStart,segmentEnd);
        tree[currentIndex]=getMin(constructST(segmentStart,mid,2*currentIndex+1),constructST(mid+1,segmentEnd,2*currentIndex+2));
    }


    void printSegmentTreeArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)(2*pow(2,h))-1; ++i)
        {
            cout<<i<<"="<<tree[i]<<endl;    //print the value at each node(array element) along with indes
        }
        cout<<"-----------------"<<endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n,l,r;
    float min;
    cout<<"Enter n";
    cin>>n;

    segmentTree st(n);
    st.getInput(n);     //function to get input array from user

    st.constructST(0,n-1,0);
    st.printSegmentTreeArray();

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

If I am constructing an `int` tree (i.e. using an integer array for storing the nodes of the Segment Tree), everything works fine. But as soon as I change the type to `float`, something mischievous happens and **indices 0-7 and index 11** of the array representing the segment tree show the value **`nan`**; while nothing of this sort happens in the case of `int` tree. The function `printSegmentTreeArray()` is for printing the value stored at each location of the array representing the tree.

NOTE:-

1.In the code, the changes required for correctly changing the data type of tree from `int` to `float` are indicated by the commented block `/* $$$ float $$$ */` in front of the `int` to be replaced.

2.I did write the function for extracting Min from queried interval but removed it out since the `constructST()` function was behaving weird.

3.I have tested my code with the following input for both the cases.

```
18
3 4 2 1 5 7 9 7 10 5 12 3 1 1 2 1 3 2
```

Can someone please point out the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `constructST` never returns anything. If you update that to return `tree[currentIndex]` you will stop getting NaNs in your results. The fact that it worked with ints was merely a lucky coincidence.

```
float constructST(int segmentStart, int segmentEnd, int currentIndex)
{
    if (segmentEnd==segmentStart)
    {
        tree[currentIndex]=timeForStick[segmentEnd];
        return timeForStick[segmentEnd];
    }

    int mid=getMid(segmentStart,segmentEnd);
    tree[currentIndex]=getMin(constructST(segmentStart,mid,2*currentIndex+1),constructST(mid+1,segmentEnd,2*currentIndex+2));
    return tree[currentIndex];
}
```

Comment: better to put as a comment

Comment: @JamesHolderness, that works!! Thanks a lot for such a quick reply. You really saved my day. Would have definitely upvoted your answer had I had some reputation.